# ExtJs 4.2 styling affects to my general style (Jsp inside another)

Tags: jquery, jsp, css, extjs4

I've problems with the styling using ExtJS4. In my jsp i have a top bar, a vertical menu bar and a wrapper div on the right side of the menu. The wrapper changes its content depending on the selection. In this case, i load a jsp inside the wrapper with an ExtJS Table. I do this with jquery invoking this function:

```
$('#wrapper').load('../admin/usersTable.html');
```

usersTable.html returns a jsp which contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head>
    <title><spring:message code="app.admin.panel.user.title"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../extjs/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/systemUsers.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h3>System users</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The script creates a table with users and renders the table to the div #container. When i invoke the load method and loads the jsp with the table in the parent jsp, the general style is affected. Ext adds some classes and an id to the body and other components. For example:

How can i manage this situation? I can include !important or avoid some Extjs stylings because i took a look with firebug but i cannot get the same style as default because it changes too many things.

Thank you all

Comment: Whats problem with using href="ext-4/resources/css/ext-all.css"

Comment: Why can't you use href="ext-4/resources/css/ext-all.css" file.